# How to remove PWA service worker and its cache from client browser after remove PWA in angular 6 website

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have added PWA features and service worker to my angular website. After the release to the live server many user started getting issues, like: "This Site Can't Be Reached", but when user clicks CTRL+ F5 then it works fine.

For immediate solution I have removed the PWA and service worker from my release. Nevertheless many users are facing the same issue or "index page not found" error from service worker.

How can I remove or unregister the old service worker from the end user's browser?

I  tried this code to remove the service worker cache :

```
if ('caches' in window) {
    caches.keys()
      .then(function(keyList) {
          return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
              return caches.delete(key);
          }));
      })
}
```

To remove the service worker I have added the following:

```
if(window.navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then(function(registrations) {
    for(let registration of registrations) {
      registration.unregister();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The code you used is correct to unregister the service worker and delete its cache from the client.

Is your SW processing any long run tasks?
Because if so, it will wait to complete that task before being removed.

In the worst scenario, your service worker will check within 24 hours if a newer version is available. This feature is called fail safe and will be triggered by the browser.

Your code is already good, but if you want to read more about [Service Workers and caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f), I wrote an article about them.

Comment: How can we clear cache and local storage from browser when we uninstall PWA ?I have created a PWA using angular

Comment: With Angular, if you deploy a dist bundle without the `ngsw.json` file, all clients using the PWA will have the cache and SW deleted. Otherwise, you can delete the old caches once the new SW reaches the `activated` lifecycle step. If you let the user uninstall the PWA from UI, then you can programmatically delete the cache using the same code in the question.

Comment: Not only cache I want to remove localstorage data as well. Right now when I am using localstorage to store jwt-token. Upon logout I am clearing it. But when user unistall the app without logout and reinstall then it is reading the token and redirecting me to dashboard. That means localstorage is still there. How can I clear it when uninstalling the app or apk ?

Comment: You then need to use the storage API, something like: `localStorage.removeItem('jwt-token');`.  You can decide when to invoke this API in your code. For example, you can replace the jwt-token (if available locally) with a new one if the SW gets installed again. This way you can ensure that if a new installation occurs, the user is working with the latest jwt-token. Of course, other ways are possible, it depends on your requirements and logic.

Comment: I have less idea in SW. Can you show an example how to write SW code when new SW is installed. If you also specify other ways to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951682/how-to-clear-local-storage-when-uninstalling-the-pwa-app?noredirect=1#comment125435684_70951682

Comment: The Angular SW is like a black box and you cannot develop it directly. You could create a base SW and import in it the built in SW plus a custom one. However, if you need to add custom logic (as in your case) I would suggest to use Workbox library and drop the Angular SW altogether. That way you can implement way more options than with just Angular SW and you are free to implement your logic: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started

Answer (score 2):

The browser will disable the service worker after its lifetime.

I have faced this issue once and it was really painful.

Hack: In your app.component.ts use the following line inside ngAfterViewInit();

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   window.location.reload(); 
}
```

This is a dirty hack not a bad practice keep this code live for few days until you know that your users have the latest version of your angular-app.

After that if you wish to use Service-Workers for PWA Use the following code to automatically update your client.

Inject 
`private swUpdate: SwUpdate, private snackbar: MatSnackBar` in constructor and write the following code inside it.

```
this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(evt => {
        let snack = this.snackbar.open('Update Available', 'Reload Please.');

        snack.onAction().subscribe(() => {
            window.location.reload();
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            snack.dismiss();
        }, 10000);
    });
```

If you still face any problem let me know that can be an interesting problem to solve.

Comment: Right now service worker have error of index.html not found on server its giving 404 for path, correct path is localhost:4200/new but its finding on localhost:4200.

In real website i have deleted serviceworker.js so who have old cache they still getting same error

Comment: Are you using NGINX for deployment? 
And please delete the ALL old files from your server where you have pasted the Angular DIST folder and paste new `ng build --prod` contents inside that directory and restart server.

Comment: i am just using ng build --prod for deployment, and deployed many time in server, but we cant restart the server it will restart other many things.