# How to clear local storage when uninstalling the PWA app

Tags: angular, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA app created with Angular 12 and I have stored some in information like jwt-token in local storage to check user user logged in. I am clearing the local-storage upon logout function.

I have created the apk of that PWA app.

Now when I close the app without logout and uninstall the app, again when I install and try to open the app it goes directly to my dashboard instead of login page. That means the localstorage information is still there in the system.

How can I clear the app data (cache , localstorage) on uninstalling the apk or app?

Comment: you will have to modify your angular service worker and add an event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/unregister to the script then do the cleanup there. That is my best guess

Comment: if you use the build in service worker you can extend it by creating a new .js file and start it with importScripts('ngsw-worker.js'); then the new serverworker you need to register instead. and there you can apply the unregister event.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Ok, I am checking with the first point you made. I am not aware of service-worker so I require some help.

Comment: the basics of a PWA is just a .js file that gets registered in the browser. For a angular it has a prebuild one that follows you ngsw-config.json settings. So if you need something custom you could do create your own file that extends the one generated by angular.

Comment: oh actually my bad this unregister is when running the app. There is no event for when you unregister it externally.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen yeah correct. Do we have something like --> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-remove-local-storage-as-app-get-uninstall/14823/24 in PWA ?

Comment: No that is native android. But its clearly cached in the browser even if you remove the PWA. So i am not quite sure how to deal with it. But if you find a solution i am keen to hear how you managed.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I will find some solution and will post the answer here.